# Populate an existing array from XML

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

I've searched averywhere, but can't find an answer that specifically applies to me.
I have a AS3 array that is currentely populated manually inside the script and the rest of the code that does something with this array. How can I 'convert' this array to populate using XML without affecting the rest of the code.
Code:

```
var my_info_array:Array = new Array("Info-pdf.swf", "Info2-pdf.swf");
//This first line I want to populate using XML without affecting the code below
var infoURLnow:Number = 0;
var myTimer2:Timer = new Timer(5000);
myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
 function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{    
if(infoURLnow != totalInfo) {
    loadINFO();
} 
else {
    infoURLnow = 0;
    loadINFO();
}
}
myTimer2.start();
loadINFO();
function loadINFO(){
var infoLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var infoURL:String = my_info_array[infoURLnow];
var infourl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(infoURL); 
infoLoader.load(infourl);
info_kozel.addChild(infoLoader); 
infoLoader.x = 20;                                        
infoLoader.y = 20; 
infoLoader.scaleX = infoLoader.scaleY =1.25;
infoURLnow = infoURLnow +1;
}
```

Something like this:

```
var data:XML = new XML();

var xml_Loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xml_Loader.load(new URLRequest("Info.xml"));

xml_Loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, do_XML);
```

Then how do I integrate the above code into do_XML function??

Comment: Can someone show me the complete code? I have tried adjusting different AS3 code from the internet but nothing works. I havee a feeling that it is very simple, but I can't quite get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var xml:XML =
    <list>
        <link>Info-pdf.swf</link>
        <link>Info2-pdf.swf</link>
    </list>;

var my_info_array:Array=[];

xml..link.(my_info_array.push(text()));

trace(my_info_array) // Info-pdf.swf,Info2-pdf.swf
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but what If I have more than 2 external swfs and need to populate this array without ever opening fla file?

Comment: Don't I need to load XML first then parse it so that data is pushed to this array?

Comment: @user3258032 Sure , put it all in an external XML and add links as much as you want!

Comment: What will the final AS3 code look like? The code above doesn't seem to have an XML loader nor parser.

Comment: @user3258032 it is impossible to not affect the rest of the code , cause XML loading is async process , so ideally is to put some stuff in XML' "ready" event' handler

Comment: Thank you very much, That worked. I just had to move the my_info_array:Array=[]; from inside a function to outside because otherwise you can't reference to it later. Thanks for your help.